# How to read last 10 line of text file using CStdioFile

Tags: c++, mfc

I would like to read last 10 lines of a big text file.
Normally I loop through the file and get the last 10 lines.
Please kindly tell me, are there other ways to read the last lines quicker.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file's length in bytes with (`CStdioFile::GetLength`) (inherited from `CFile`):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b569d0t4(v=VS.80).aspx

And you can use `CStdioFile::Seek` to jump to an arbitrary offset:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8c5ccz0x(v=VS.80).aspx

If the line length is fixed, it's a pretty easy problem to read the last N lines.  But there's no "read backwards" operation, and in the general case you don't know how long the lines in an arbitrary text file are.  (You could build and maintain an index file that kept track of it, if you wanted to do this faster.)

Be aware that seeking and reading one character at a time may be inefficient.  Exactly *how* inefficient depends on several factors.  Although buffering at the operating system level *might* make it not as terrible as it could be if it went back to the disk each time, there's always going to be overhead each time you seek and each time you call a read operation.

So you would probably be better off picking a buffer size, and step through reading chunks.  As a strong indication that this is useful, see some source code for the UNIX called `tail`.  It gets the last N lines of a file, and although it's written in C it might give you some insight:

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c#n477

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
I have fixed length line. So I can just seek to the line I want and start reading. :)

Comment: The efficiency of the approach is guaranteed by the buffer-cache level of the operating system. I politely request you to erase that part of the answer; it is obvious that you don't like that approach, but there is no reason to mention it in your answer. Please consider changing that by a comment to my answer.

Comment: @Baltasarq: First, seeks can flush buffers. It depends on the operating system implementation as to how clever it is whether it does this. A full flush isn't the only potential source of inefficiency, as function call overhead and the per-read-operation to check to see if a buffer should be used isn't completely free either.

Comment: I've generalized my answer to not mention you specifically and instead pointed to my answer in a comment on yours.  Better?

Comment: One reason to read a (fairly large) block at a time is because it's usually more efficient to read sectors in their proper order rather than backwards. Reading a sector at a time backwards may mean the disk has spin almost a whole revolution between each sector read on the same track, rather than reading multiple sectors per revolution. This is probably unimportant for small numbers of reasonably-sized lines, though.

Answer (score 0):

In binary files, you (normally) have a fixed record length. In text files, one possibility is to consider the text line as the record in which you divide the contents of the file. Unfortunately, lines are not of fixed size in regular text files, so you cannot rely in a formula such as:

```
lastTenthLine = ( LengthOfFile / LengthOfLine ) - 10;
```

The only way I can think of is to move the reading pointer to the end of the file. Tne start reading backwards, one char each time, and count the number of times you pass over a '\n' char. Once you have counted ten times, you can return the next char position.

*(Note that you can have "end line issues" depending on the origin (OS) of the files you are using as example. Since you are ussing MFC, you won't have any problem as long as the files used were generated in Windows)*

Since I suppose this is homework, I won't post code. You have documentation about MFC here, explaining how to deal with files. You need the `CFile::Read` and `CFile::Seek` methods (apart from Open and Close). Note that `CFile` is the parent class of `CStdioClass`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey6xh9bk(v=vs.80).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: I sure hope it's *not* homework, because that would suggest there's someplace in the world teaching a class that uses MFC!  :-/

Comment: Seeking/reading one character at a time can be inefficient.  See my answer.  A lot of I/O operations are more complex than they look: http://hostilefork.com/2010/03/14/where-the-printf-rubber-meets-the-road/

Comment: @Hostile Fork, thanks for taking my requests int account. Thanks also for pointing this whole issue out.